# inheritance in Grails domain model causes duplicate foreign keys

Tags: hibernate, grails, grails-orm

In the domain model of my Grails 2.5.0 app I have two classes `Income` and `Benefit` that have identical properties. I would like to store these in separate database tables, but move the common fields into a base class. The model I've come up with is:

```
class Assessment {

    Date dateCreated = new Date()
    User user

    static hasMany = [incomes: Income, benefits: Benefit]
}

class Benefit extends IncomeSource {}

class Income extends IncomeSource {}

abstract class IncomeSource {

    String name
    BigDecimal amount
    PaymentFrequency frequency

    static belongsTo = [assessment: Assessment]

    static mapping = {
        tablePerHierarchy false
    }
}
```

This causes the following tables to be generated for the relationship between `Assessment` and `Benefit`

[image]

The tables created for the the relationship between `Assessment` and `Benefit` are (unsurprisingly) identical.

Rather than having an `assessment_benefit` join table between `assessment` and `benefit`, I would prefer to have an `assessment_id` foreign key in the `benefit` table, thereby eliminating the need for the join table.

How can I change my domain model to achieve this?

Comment: What is the Grails version used? I have used Grails 2.4.4 and used the domain classes provided by you i.e. Assessment, Benefit, Income and IncomeSource. It has not created extra join table as you have mentioned. And it has added `assessment_id` in benefit, income, and income_source tables. So it would be easy to verify if you provide the Grails version used by you for this examples.

Comment: I'm using Grails 2.5.0

Comment: Did it work as shown in the answer?

Answer (score 1):

> *How can I change my domain model to achieve this?*

Move

```
static belongsTo = [assessment: Assessment]
```

from abstract parent `IncomeSource` to child `Benefit` as:

```
class Benefit extends IncomeSource {
    static belongsTo = [assessment: Assessment]
}
```

You can also keep this relation in the base class and just copy `belongsTo` to child as well.

No join table will be created for `Assessment` and `Benefit` in either case.

Same would be applicable for `Income`, if similar behavior is required.

*Applicable for Grails 2.5.0*